# Cmake file for a Folly project

Tags: c++, folly

I am trying to write a toy example to use Facebook's `Folly` [library](https://github.com/facebook/folly). The program is brought in what follows:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <folly/Format.h>
#include <folly/futures/Future.h>
#include <folly/executors/ThreadedExecutor.h>
#include <folly/Uri.h>
#include <folly/FBString.h>

static void print_uri(const folly::fbstring &address)
{
  const folly::Uri uri(address);
  const auto authority = folly::format("The authority from {} is {}", uri.fbstr(), uri.authority());
  std::cout << authority << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  folly::ThreadedExecutor executor;
  folly::Promise<folly::fbstring> promise;
  folly::Future<folly::fbstring> future = promise.getSemiFuture().via(&executor);
  folly::Future<folly::Unit> unit = std::move(future).thenValue(print_uri);
  promise.setValue("https://conan.io/");
  std::move(unit).get();
  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that I am not sure what are the required libraries for compiling such a program. I would be very grateful if someone can share the `CMakeList.txt` file for a `Folly` project.

Comment: Use can use vcpkg Microsoft packager to automatically install folly libraries into your vc++ project.

Comment: Have you actually tried to `find_package(folly REQUIRED)`? According to [this file](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/CMake/folly-config.cmake.in) they provide the target `Folly::folly` and variables `FOLLY_INCLUDE_DIRS`, `FOLLY_LIBRARIES`. I didn't try it, but it seems quite trivial.

Comment: Thank you very much @Ptaq666. It helped and I made the CMakeLists. I'll post it below to help others with similar questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the required `CMakeLists.txt` for making a `Folly` project.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
find_package(folly REQUIRED)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
find_package(gflags REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
#include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
#include_directories(${folly_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set_and_check(FOLLY_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/local/include/folly)
set_and_check(FOLLY_CMAKE_DIR /usr/local/lib/cmake/folly)
if (NOT TARGET Folly::folly)
  include("${FOLLY_CMAKE_DIR}/folly-targets.cmake")
endif()


set(FOLLY_LIBRARIES Folly::folly)

if (NOT folly_FIND_QUIETLY)
  message(STATUS "Found folly: ${PACKAGE_PREFIX_DIR}")
endif()

add_executable(HelloWorld main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(HelloWorld ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${FOLLY_LIBRARIES})
```